# i have a date (eg: 2010-04-17 ) i need the date of after 20 days from this date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datetime, date

i have a date (eg: 2010-04-17 ) i need the date of after 20 days from this date
How to get the date after 20 days i.e next month some date.

either in sql or in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T-SQL: `DATEADD(DAY, 20, thedate)`

C#: `DateTime.Add()`

Answer (score 10):

This is quite simple in C#

```
            DateTime date = new DateTime(2010, 04, 17);
            DateTime newDate = date.AddDays(20);
```

You can construct the original date variable in whatever way is easiest to you, then use the AddDays method to create a new variable (or update the existing one) with the date any number of days afterwards.

Comment: you should set this as the answer then!

Answer (score 4):

In C# you use the AddDays method:

```
DateTime someDate = new DateTime(2010, 4, 17);
DateTime later = someDate.AddDays(20);
```

In SQL you would use some date manipulation function, which is specific to the different dialects of SQL. In MS SQL Server for example you would use the `dateadd` function:

```
dateadd(day, 20, someDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the date is already a DateTime object, then you can call

```
var nextDate = myDate.AddDays(20);
```

If it's a string then you will need to firt convert it to a DateTime:

```
var myDate = DateTime.Parse("2010-04-17");
var nextDate = myDate.AddDays(20);
```

Note that the AddDays method returns a new DateTime, it doesn't add days to the original DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle:

```
SELECT DATE_COLUMN + INTERVAL '20' DAY FROM MY_TABLE;
```

or

```
SELECT DATE_COLUMN + 20 FROM MY_TABLE;
```

PL/SQL:

```
BEGIN
  dtMy_date  DATE;

  SELECT DATE_COLUMN INTO dtMy_date FROM MY_TABLE;

  dtMy_date := dtMy_date + INTERVAL '20' DAY;
  -- or
  dtMy_date := dtMy_date + 20;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.